# Eclipse not found package android.view

Tags: android, eclipse, view, package

I'm new on android when I try to create object of **OnClickListener** and import **android.view.view** I have an error "**Create view class in package android.view**" and when I import **android.view.view.OnClickListener** I have an error "**Create class OnClickListener in package android.view.view**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/*this is the creation of an OnClickListener*/

```
View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do the things u need to do when u click the view
            }
        };
```

/*this is the part when u set the on click listener*/

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```

Another way to do that is to implement the on click listener

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
   //the code  of your activity
   @Override
   public void onCreate(...){
       myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    //some other methods
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId == R.id.theIdOfTheViewInXML)
        //do the things u need to do when u click the view
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks its work the problem in second view that was a small letters.

Comment: :) next time don't write the imports yourself , just implement them and than eclipse helps you import the interface and implements its methods.